# Magento 2.3 - custom import module with magmi integration

Tags: magento2, module, magmi, product-import

I'm trying to write a magento module for importing products from a csv file. I would like to use Magmi to achieve the import. I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
   namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Home;
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../../../../../../lib/magmi/inc/magmi_defs.php");
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../../../../../../lib/magmi/integration/inc/magmi_datapump.php");

  class Import extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{

     public function execute()
    {

        // getting data from a casv file 

        for ($items as $item){
           $dp = Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");
           $dp->beginImportSession("default", "xcreate");
           $item = "product field array";
           $run = $dp->ingest($item);
           $dp->endImportSession();
        }

    }

}
```

I receive errors on the Magmi classes "**class not found**". I tried also different code but the only way a think it can works is using class file named, e.g. Datapump.php with e defined class named Datapump. But I cannot rewrite all files of magmi to make it works, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I hope someone of you knows how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Code:**

```
    namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Home;
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "../../../../../../../lib/magmi/inc/magmi_defs.php");
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "../../../../../../../lib/magmi/integration/inc/magmi_datapump.php");

    class Import extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{

         public function execute()
        {
          try{
            // getting data from a casv file 

            for ($items as $item){
               $dp = \Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");
               $dp->beginImportSession("default", "xcreate");
               $item = "product field array";
               $run = $dp->ingest($item);
               $dp->endImportSession();
            }
          }catch(\Exception $e) {

        }

    }
```